# displaying multiple photo's using Nimbus network photo application

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios, ipad, nimbus-ios

I am looking at the Nimbus photo application example and it seems that it always allows paging for the photo. Is it even possible to turn off paging so I can see 2-3 image in a view instead of one at a time? Also I want to have a loosely scroll (i.e: doesn't snap when I switch between images). How do I do this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

see this demo it is usefull for select multiple photo from library and display it in scrollview with pagging

https://github.com/ForrestShi/UploadPhotoFB